# how to use one sql insert data to two table?

Tags: oracle

I have two table,and they are connected by one field : B_ID of table A & id of table B.

I want to use sql to insert data to this two table.

how to write the insert sql ?

1,id in table B is auto-increment.

2,in a stupid way,I can insert data to table B first,and then select the id from table B,then add the id to table A as message_id.

[image: table A]

[image: table B]

Comment: That's not a stupid way - it's how you do it - you need to generate the id before you can put it in the other table and the only way to do that is to insert the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot insert data to multiple tables in one SQL statement. Just insert data first to B table and then table A. You could use RETURNING statement to get ID value and get rid of additional select statement between inserts.

See: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dml-returning-into-clause

Comment: you could also use a trigger, specifically `AFTER INSERT` - see my answer for details

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about [`AFTER INSERT`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_insert.php) trigger? I think it is what you are looking for.

Something like this might do what you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TableB_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON TableB
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
   v_id int;

BEGIN
   /*
    * 1. Select your id from TableB
    * 2. Insert data to TableA
    */
END;

/
```

Comment: But how i write the sql of 1. Select your id from TableB ?